# Editing config spec after creating branch

Tags: clearcase

I wanted to create a dynamic view with the following config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../view_1_1/LATEST
element * LABEL_1 -mkbranch view_1_1
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch view_1_1
```

Unfortunately I have written the config spec wrong; I didn't write the "`...`" in the second line (`element * /view_1_1/LATEST`). After this, I have given the '`mkbrtype -global -c "some comment" view_1_1`' command and make it visible in Windows (ClearCase Explorer) using Region Synchronizer.

And I realized that I have forgotten '`...`', so I corrected the config spec. I corrected this before any checkouts, checkins or something.

Does this edit cause any problems, or any differences than other views created with the correct config specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this edit cause any problems, or any differences than other views created with the correct config specs?

No, this edit is in the config spec of your view, and remains local to this view.
It has nothing to do with the fact the view tag was made visible through the Region Synchronizer.

The [OP groove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422336/groove) asks in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429817/editing-config-spec-after-creating-branch#comment32332803_21430434):

> Is this true for editing config spec after "mkbrtype" too?

Yes: the `brtype` can change, the config spec will use that modified `brtype` at the next refresh.
The '...' is a simple **selection rule** modification, which means it will select different elements based on the new rule (`.../view_1_1/LATEST` instead of `/view_1_1/LATEST` or `/main/view_1_1/LATEST`).
If the `brtype` doesn't exist yet, or if its comment changes, that selection rule would simply be ignored.

Comment: @groove Yes, it remains true, and doesn't involve any issue. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

config spec is read from the top to bottom by actived view. If the view finds one version of file/folder's tree, stop reading the next config spec.

In your case, when the view read second line `element * /view_1_1/LATEST`, since there is no branch /view_1_1, just ignore it, nothing happens, and continuously read the rest.

`mkbrtype` is used to define the properties and create branch type `view_1_1` (not create the branch on that element). You need know command `mkbrtype` and `mkbranch` are different.

```
mkbranch
Creates a new branch in the version tree of an element
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbranch.htm

```
mkbrtype
Creates/updates a branch type object
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm